How to issue USB standard control request (SET INTERFACE) to the device
Based on the MSDN reference, found out we can issue a USB standard request ,"SET_INTERFACE " by calling WdfUsbInterfaceSelectSetting() .This can be done by specifying the alternate setting number assigned by the USB driver stack. Typically, its the same index used while enumerating the settings.
While the SelectSetting call passes but on checking the USB transaction logs found out the SET_INTERFACE command is not issued.
Is there any other way to issue "SET_INTERFACE standard request or anything that can be tried to check the reason ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
